# vb.net dynamic accesing dynamic controls

Tags: c#, vb.net, dynamic, composite

I have placed a `FlowLayoutPanel` in a WinForm
and created a composite control named `ContactW`

With a loop I have filled the `FlowLayoutPanel` with several `ContactW` objects

```
For index = 0 To 99
    Dim Contact As New ContactW.BaseContactW()
    Contact.Tag = index
    'Here I could set properties
    '....
    AddHandler Contact.ContactClickEvt, AddressOf GenericClick
    flp_ContaninerContacts.Controls.Add(Contact)
Next
```

`GenericClick` gets the `ContactW` object, and I can modify it's properties

```
Public Sub GenericClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim cwa As ContactW.BaseContactW = CType(sender, ContactW.BaseContactW)
    MessageBox.Show("you have clicked " & CType(CType(sender, System.Object).Tag, String))
    cwa.ContactName = "Robert"
End Sub
```

But I would like to modify properties of a `ContactW` using index or Tag for example like this:

```
Contact(21).ContactName = "Julia"
Contact(21).ContactAge = 35
Contact(21).ContactStatus = "Married"
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Controls` collection that you added the controls to in the first place is a collection, so you just index it like you would any other collection.

Comment: which one is de Controls collection?
flp_ContaninerContacts.Controls?

Comment: If I try `flp_ContaninerContacts.Controls(1)` I can't access the properties.

Comment: You're getting a `Control` reference because the collection can contain any type of control.  You have to cast it as a specific type to access members of that type.

Comment: Thanks.
Placing `Dim cwa As ContactW.BaseContactW = CType(flp_ContainerContacts.Controls(3), ContactW.BaseContactW)`
`cwa.ContactName = "Julian"` I get access to the properties. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: I would consider `DirectCast` to be better then `CType` but it's not a big deal.